# Hot deploy with maven overlay

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, hotdeploy

So I'm trying to get hot deploy to work on my maven project using netbeans. I have two war packages. One I call "web" and the other I call "custom-web". I overlay (with the maven overlay plugin) "custom-web" on top of "web". I have several "custom-web" projects, one for each of my clients. So maven overlays were a good fit for my needs.

The problem is I really, really want to get hot deployment of classes and static files (.js, .css) on both projects. But the hot-deployment only works on the "custom-web" projects, if I modify a class or static file on "web" the changes are not reflected on the server unless I manually rebuild "web" and do a redeploy of the whole application which can take from 3 to 5 minutes, severely hindering my development.

I'm using Netbeans with the "deploy on save" option and the "apply code changes" when in debug mode. Both do not work on "web" files/classes.

I'm looking for a solution. My custom-web project will mostly have static files, but it can also have classes. It does not need to use overlays necessarily, but I can't figure out any other way to properly add two projects together without using overlays.

Comment: Good question.  This has worked out-of-the-box for me when using STS 2.9+ on Windows7 when both 'web' and 'web-overlay' projects are open and am running webapp using a Tomcat or tcServer inside STS.  I think it is the WTP eclipse plugin specifically that does the overlaying magic.  However exact same setup on LinuxMint does NOT work (does not do the overlay).

Comment: @sbk I'm using netbeans with glassfish. I'm open to changing servers but not the ide.

Comment: Fair call.  Just saying what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether that's an option, but using Jetty works great in this case. Using the `jetty:run` goal, you can point Jetty to the source directories to watch (across projects), and Jetty will always serve the files from there.

In your case, you would point Jetty's `scanTargets` to your source directories, and Jetty will serve the files from there.

See http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#jetty-run-goal for configuration options and an example.

Comment: sounds interesting, I will try that. How is j2ee support on jetty? I'm using a lot of j2ee stuff (ejbs, managed beans, jsf and such)

Comment: I have used some of that on Jetty, e.g. JSF, but I haven't tried to deploy any EJBs on there.

Comment: Here's a link to another question mentioning running Geronimo on top of Jetty for EJBs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9024108/1228454

Comment: You known any other application servers that support that scanTagets option or a similar option?

Comment: Sorry, I'm only aware of Jetty with this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Maven profile (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) is maybe a solution. You can create a "dev" one with your "web" project having dev configurations and "deploy on save" stuff.

In netbeans, you can map configurations with profiles : http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices#Configurations

Finally use the overlay options for your customized projects and your CI server.